# TS message in React Native and React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I made two projects, in my react project with npx, whenever i dont use typescript(where is supose to be) i get an error message:

[image]

[image]

and in my React Native project with expo, i dont get any messages

[image]

How can i set my react native project to send me this error message from typescript?

My react-native tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add typescript to your expo managed project. Have a look at [the official docs](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/typescript/) on how to do it.

Comment: I did, my package.json is showing typescript. I think maybe is some configuration in my tsconfig.json(is almost empty)

Comment: try adding the rule ```"noImplicitAny": true,``` to your compilerOptions in tsconfig

Comment: Didnt work either. Maybe is a package.json eslint thing?

Comment: It could well be related to eslint. It depends on how your IDE/Code Editor is configured. Compare your compilerOptions in both projects and match the rules. If that doesn't do it then you are probably missing rules from .eslintrc.js file.

Answer (score 0):

In my function i used const Home: React.FC = () =>,
if you use React.FC all the things inside () are typed, so i used function Home(){ and it worked.